# Cambiar orden de números en una variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente variable:

```
$id = "10,2,5,1";
```

Esta variable se utiliza para esta consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id in ($id)
```

Lo que necesito es invertir el orden de los números para ordenar la salida al revés. Es decir, introducir en la consulta el orden de `$id` y ordenarlos al revés de como entraron (sustituyo la variable `$id` por su contenido en el siguiente ejemplo):

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id in (10,2,5,1) ORDER BY FIELDS(id, 1,5,2,10)
```

No sé como invertir el contenido de la variable `$id` para ordenarlos como necesito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
$id = "10,2,5,1";
$ids = explode(",", $id);
$idReves = "";
for($i=count($ids)-1;$i>=0;$i--){
    $idReves = $idReves.$ids[$i];
    if($i!=0){
        $idReves = $idReves.',';
    }
}
```

Al final $idReves tendria el valor de $id al reves.

Comment: Muchas gracias!